# Zapier not sending all data in body of request

Tags: javascript, zapier, zapier-cli

I'm trying to send some data to an API but Zapier will only send the first line that is in my body any suggestions on how to get all the data to send to the API. So in the code below the `z.JSON.stringify(bundle.inputData.data)` will send but 
`'items': stringify(bundle.inputData.items)` will not send.

```
const options = {
  url: 'https://us1.pdfgeneratorapi.com/api/v3/templates/41993/output',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'X-Auth-Key': 'censored:64:5ebbff0676',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'X-Auth-Secret': 'censored:64:a5e9b35af8',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'X-Auth-Workspace': 'censored:27:384b1d0d0f'
  },
  params: {
    'format': 'pdf',
    'output': 'url'

  },
  body: z.JSON.stringify(bundle.inputData.data),
    'items': z.JSON.stringify(bundle.inputData.items)

};

return z.request(options)
  .then((response) => {
    response.throwForStatus();
    const results = z.JSON.parse(response.content);

    // You can do any parsing you need for results here before returning them

    return results;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working as intended. You're sending the `items` property in the `options` object, which `z.request` doesn't recognize and is ignoring. If you only want to send `bundle.inputData.items`, then assign that to the `body` property. If you want to combine them, then do something like `body: {items: bundle.inputData.items, body: bundle.inputData.data}`

Comment: thanks for your reply. here is what I want the data to send like dpaste.de/qNj1 let me know how I can achieve this. Im having a issue with the arrays. As you will see in the sample data there is the main array that has everything and then the array for the Items so how can I combine them and the send them to the endpoint?